# Redirect all subdomains to a subfolder, excluding www

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Here's what I have so far, and it works, but I want to exclude (www)

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} [^.]+\.example\.com.*$
RewriteRule (.*) sub/$1 [L]
```

**EDIT:** 
For example `jason.example.com` would redirect to `example.com/sub/`
BUT `www.example.com` would stay on the root directory: `example.com/`

Comment: `but I want to exclude (www)...` ¿From the rule or from the substitution URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the rule not to be applied when the hostname starts with `www` or doesn't have a subdomain at all, then you can exclude it by modifying your regex:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).*)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) sub/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use Virtual Hosts in Apache instead of the configuration file.

Here is a cool tutorial about it:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/apache-virtual-host/

Cheers!

Comment: If this is under some hosting service, you have no control over the vhost config, and often times these services would just park add-on domains under the same document root.